# How to pass a string to cmd from Python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am trying to execute an .exe file taking several parameters from cmd which I call from a python script, however it does not work.

When I use

```
print("C:/path_to_exe/file.exe -param1 " + param2 + " param3")
```

it gives me exactly what I want to run in cmd. However when I use

```
os.system("C:/path_to_exe/file.exe -param1 " + param2 + " param3"),
```

where `param2 = "filename.bin"`, `file.exe` launches but the parameters are passed incorrectly. The same happens when I use `subprocess.call()`. Is there a way to simply pass a string to cmd? `os.system()` is supposed to do exactly that but it does not. It does not work with double back slashes as well, it does not work if I change the directory first and then run the .exe file (which always runs just does not take the parameters correctly).

Comment: Do any of these parameters contain spaces? Programs such as file.exe almost always parse the command line into arguments delimited by spaces.

Comment: Yes they do, but I accounted for that. The expression in brackets is exactly what I want to run in cmd. When I print it then copy and paste into cmd it works as expected.

Comment: I'd build the command line in steps using string interpolation. For example,  `exepath = r'C:\path_to_exe\file.exe';` `cmdline = '"%s" "%s" "%s" "%s"' % (exepath, param1, param2, param3)`. Then run `os.system('"%s"' % cmdline)`. I've put each component of the command line in double quotes, in case any contains spaces, and then wrapped the entire command line in double quotes due to a quirk of how cmd.exe works.

Comment: I meant to say the parameters themselves don't contain any spaces, but I make spaces between them within the string.

Comment: But actually I wouldn't use `os.system` for this at all. I'd use `rc = subprocess.call([exepath, param1, param2, param3])`, which will internally call `subprocess.list2cmdline` to properly build the command line string (at least for most applications that use VC++ rules) and avoids the potential security problems with using the shell.

Comment: @eryksun thanks, but I encounter the same problem with subprocess. The .exe launches but the parameters aren't passed correctly.

Comment: Please provide example parameter values.

Comment: @eryksun the second parameter param2 = "file_name.bin". Param3 = 1. The first parameter is pretty much what I've given.

Comment: You've tried `rc = subprocess.call([r"C:\path_to_exe\file.exe", "-param1", "file_name.bin", "1"])`?

Comment: @eryksun Yes, tried that. Get an error from the .exe file.

Comment: What error exactly? Can it not find "file_name.bin" as an input file? This name is relative to the working directory of your script. Print `os.getcwd()` to see what that is.

Comment: @eryksun the error is produced by the .exe file which does not state what the error is. I used `os.chdir()` as well as tried to give it a full path to no avail.

Comment: A lot of programs require paths in the command line to use backslash as the path separator. If you're using forward slash for the fully-qualified path, first normalize it to use backslash via `os.path.normpath`.

Comment: Still does not help. I don't encounter problems with paths when copying files or launching the executable. Both double backslashes and forward slashes work. I also tried your suggestion.

Comment: Make sure `os.getcwd()` is the same directory as what works in the command prompt, and then run the exact same command line that works there; copy and paste and use a raw string, e.g. `subprocess.call(r'C:\path_to_exe\file.exe -param1 file_name.bin 1')`. This is skipping the args list, so the executable will get *exactly* the command line you pass it here.

Comment: The same problem persists. It's what I described in the beginning,  if I print the string then copy and paste it to cmd everything works. But it does not work with `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()`

Comment: @eryksun thanks a lot your solution works. If I paste what I run in cmd back to the py script then it works. I don't understand why it does not work if I paste to cmd what I get from `print`

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you mean by "the parameters are passed incorrectly." What behavior *exactly* do you get from `os.system`? It will help if you come up with *actual* values (especially for `param2`), instead of expecting us to debug this in our imagination.

Comment: @alexis eryksun just figured the solution. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: That's not really a solution. It's more of a last-ditch effort to see if anything at all would work. It doesn't explain the problem. It's just the beginning of trying to unravel what the real problem is. But doing that via a game of 20 questions is difficult.

Comment: In the sense that it's still unclear why `os.system()` and `subprocess.call()` do not work while `print()` gives the exact string that works in cmd, maybe it's not. But at least there is a known way to make it work. Here is a working option:

`rc = subprocess.call(r'C:/path_to_exe/file.exe -param1 '+param2+r' param3')`, where `param2 = "filename.bin"`.